# how to know indexpath of UITableView.visibleCells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
NSArray * arrayOfVisibleTVC=[BNUtilitiesQuick ListController].tableViewA.visibleCells;
NSLog(@"array : %@", arrayOfVisibleTVC);
```

will display

```
"<UITableViewCell: 0x76c22a0; frame = (0 0; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x76bf770>>",
"<UITableViewCell: 0x76cfec0; frame = (0 75; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x769d260>>",
"<UITableViewCell: 0xe245f70; frame = (0 150; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xe245ed0>>",
"<UITableViewCell: 0xe248980; frame = (0 225; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xe2488c0>>",
"<UITableViewCell: 0xe24afa0; frame = (0 300; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xe24aee0>>"
```

and with this

```
UITableViewCell * lastObjectOfArray=arrayOfVisibleTVC.lastObject;
int indexpathLastObject= (lastObjectOfArray.frame.origin.y/new.frame.size.height);
```

I know the last of arrayOfVisibleTVC.lastObject that I use to get indexpath. but I think there is an another way to get indexpath of TableViewcell that showed.. any one can help me?

so I can get indexpath of cell as integer

Comment: Did you try the ***indexPathForCell:*** method?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here is method in UITableView class:

**objective-c**

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

**Swift**

```
public var indexPathsForVisibleRows: [NSIndexPath]? { get }
```

Comment: @Ramis This fine unless you are using visible rows indexpath to add and delete rows, which causes rows added or deleted at wrong index.

Comment: @AshishPisey Question was about visible rows and the answer is about visible rows.

Answer (score 10):

UITableView has a method to find the indexPath of a cell:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
```

Just iterate over your visible cells array and pass each cell to get the index path.

```
for (UITableViewCell *cell in arrayOfVisibleTVC) {
  NSIndexPath *path = [[BNUtilitiesQuick ListController].tableViewA indexPathForCell:cell];
  NSLog(@"%@", path);
}
```

Comment: Way to much code for something that can be a lot easier, see Ramis answer